# Is there a name for words like "hearsay"

Tags: meaning

This is obviously a combination word, more so than a contraction, of two verbs, and the definition is almost on point for when you put the definitions of the component  verbs together.  Almost.  One could almost intuit the definition.  Another word like this is skiptrace. So is there a word for this type of word, and are there more examples?

Comment: Do you mean a *compound*?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Yes, but a specialized compound made from verbs.  Not like mothball or cabdriver.

Answer (score 2):

These could be called compound single-word verbs, to differentiate from other compound words such as *moonlight* (though, admittedly, *to moonlight* is a verb, albeit a noun-noun compound).

Example of verb-verb compound verbs: *stirfry*.

In linguistics, there's a technical term "serial verb constructions" (SVC). [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024384117301638) aims to show that verb-verb compounds in English (and Jordanian Arabic) are examples of SVC. It gives other examples: *kickstart*, *crash-land*, *sleep-walk*.

Comment: Hearsay is a noun. Skiptrace is a noun.  I think you mean verb compounds.  The example is spot on.

Comment: I would think *moonlight* is a noun-noun compound that eventually created a verb. *Moonlight* the noun is Middle English; *to moonlight* is 19th century. (I agree the examples are really useful!)

Comment: @KDog: you're right - I ignored the noun-ness of 'hearsay' etc. and only paid attention the reference to the participating verbs and away I went. Tunnel vision, I'm afraid.